# PostgreSQL 11 does not use a JSONB GIN index for a WHERE clause that contains an AND clause with two indexed expressions

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a pretty simple table with a JSONB field called **body**.  In this body there are two top-level values "type" and "director" I have a simple GIN index on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX swapi_gin ON swapi USING gin (body);
```

If I do explains on queries for either field:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT url FROM swapi WHERE body @> '{"director": "George Lucas"}';
EXPLAIN SELECT url FROM swapi WHERE body @> '{"type": "films"}';
```

Both nicely use my index.  But neither of the following queries use the index at all:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT url FROM swapi WHERE body @> '{"director": "George Lucas", "type": "films"}'; 
EXPLAIN SELECT url FROM swapi WHERE body @> '{"type": "films"}' AND body @> '{"director": "George Lucas"}';
```

Here is a detailed output as requested:

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) SELECT url FROM swapi WHERE body @> '{"director": "George Lucas", "type": "films"}';
                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on swapi  (cost=0.00..39.59 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.018..1.030 rows=4 loops=1)
   Filter: (body @> '{"type": "films", "director": "George Lucas"}'::jsonb)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 203
   Buffers: shared hit=37
 Planning Time: 0.079 ms
 Execution Time: 1.056 ms
(6 rows)
```

Both show as sequential scans.  I would think a query optimizer would at least pick one of the expressions and do an index scan.  I am guessing that I could do a sub-query with just one of the where conditions and then sequential scan the results of the sub-query.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Works for me.  Please show a reproducible test case.

Comment: Thanks - I just added the detail.  I hope this is not another case that I just need to add 10,000 filler rows to get the index to kick in for the last two queries.

Comment: It takes just over one millisecond to do sequential scan. That means that the table is pretty small. That might be the reason not to use the index twice, once for each condition. Could you try again with a lot more data?

Comment: I added a bunch of records and the queries started using the indexes.  I am building a course and don't want to make every sample database a million rows just to demonstrate indexes.  And I have no way to know if the only reason an index was not used was the number of records :(